# Access certificate content from loadUserByUsername

Tags: spring, spring-security, x509certificate

I am working on an spring mvc app which needs to do the following authentication

1. validate the client cert by tomcat cert store
2. validate additional attributes of the client cert

I try to implement #2 using loadUserByUsername() but don't know how to access the certificate content in loadUserByUsername()?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102721/how-to-get-the-certificate-into-the-x509-filter-spring-security) related. The posted answer is to read it from `HttpServletRequest`. Can I access `HttpServletRequest` from `loadUserByUsername()`?

I tried

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

but the Authentication object is not set at in `loadUserByUsername()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Having done a little bit of digging, I discovered that the Java Config provides a very easy way to get at the X509Certificate with a simple implementation of the AuthenticationUserDetailsService:

```
@Configuration
protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .x509()
            .authenticationUserDetailsService(new X509AuthenticatedUserDetailsService());
    }

    protected static class X509AuthenticatedUserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token)
                throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)token.getCredentials();
            // do your extra checking here...

            // add granted authorities, etc.
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

            // generate your user how you deem fit
            User user = new User(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(), null, authorities);
            return user;
        }

    }
}
```

Note that in the loadUserDetails method you do the same thing really as you would do when implementing `UserDetailsService` with the exception that this method takes the entire `Authentication` object.

**ORIGINAL**

I'm not sure if this is the intended way; however, the `X509Certificate` is passed along via the authentication token generated in the `X509AuthenticationFilter`. Invoking `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken#getCredentials` should get the certificate for you.

Digging a bit through the API shows that the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` could be configured with a custom `UserDetailsChecker` and `AuthenticatedUserDetailsService`. These may be sufficient for you to extract the details from the `X509Certificate` and verify them.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I am using Spring Security 3.0 and I think it doesn't support Java Config.  I wonder how I can set up the x509 filtering to call the X509AuthenticatedUserDetailsService in the security.xml

Comment: From the documentation, it appears that the user-details-ref wants a UserDetailsService so I don't believe you can use the <x509> tag. Instead, you would configure `X509AuthenticationFilter` directly in the xml. You can find a pretty good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478589/springsecurity-custom-automatic-authentication where you would replace com.example.MyPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter with the X509AuthenticationFilter from Spring.

Comment: Thanks Josh!  I got it working now by following your suggestion.

Comment: This is a great answer that needs more love.  Use `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` to access the full object! Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solutions was fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do get certificate ID from id in the following implementation of UserDetailsService. It is a simple configuration in security.xml
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String id) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
Security.xml

But just in case of the certificate onAuthenticationSuccess is not called in the public class myAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

Any suggestions? ideas?