# Spring Boot - Reading x509 client certificate from HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, certificate, x509

How to receive a x509 certificate from client? I'm using Java's Spring-Boot-Framework with embedded tomcat. For protyping I configured this with Java SE:

> HttpsExchange httpsExchange = (HttpsExchange) httpReq;
>
> name = httpsExchange.getSSLSession().getPeerPrincipal().getName();

A user gave me a reference to do this here (down below)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/grab")
public void grabCert(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    Certificate[] certs = 
            (Certificate[]) servletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
}
```

But I'm not able to get some certificate! Maybe because I'm using tomcat, and it is handling all SSL-Connections. So that no certificate is receiving my application. What I have to do, to get the clients certificate? The client certificate is used to get https connection. I need some information from the subject of the certificate. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the certificate into the X509 filter (Spring Security)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102721/how-to-get-the-certificate-into-the-x509-filter-spring-security)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to get it from the `HttpServletRequest`.

You can check the answer to this question: [How to get the certificate into the X509 filter (Spring Security)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102721/how-to-get-the-certificate-into-the-x509-filter-spring-security/1104385#1104385):

> No you can't get it that way.  You need to grab it from the HttpServletRequest:
>
> ```
> X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
> ```

This was the post I was trying to point you to, written by Gandalf.

And this was the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102721/how-to-get-the-certificate-into-the-x509-filter-spring-security/1104385)

Answer (score 2):

When you upgrade to Spring Boot 3.x the servlet request attribute has been renamed to be consistent with the renamed `javax` to `jakarta` packages. So now it's:

```java
request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate")
```